# What is the purpose of "procedure Register;" in delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, procedure

I got a code in one of the old project in `Delphi`.

In that there is a statement `procedure Register;` in definition block (i.e. Before Implementation Block started) of delphi.

As I know the both `procedure` and  `Register` are keywords in delphi.

I am bit curious about the working of this type of declaration.

Can anyone tell me what is impact of this statement `procedure Register;`?

The statement is declared as follows:

```
unit TestProj
interface
  uses
    .
  type 
    .
    . // some other declarations
    .
    .
  procedure Register;
implementation
  . 
  .  // Implementation part of all classes and functions
end.
```

Thanks in Advanced..

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Declaring_the_Register_Procedure

Comment: Don't get fooled by the fact that the IDE editor highlights `Register` like a keyword. It's just a procedure name here.

Comment: @UliGerhardt Is it mean that I can use any Keyword as a name for procedure?

Comment: No. I don't know the correct terminology right now, but there are "normal" keywords like `for` and context-sensitive keywords (directives?) like `register` or `index`. You can only use the second kind as identifiers.

Comment: The `Register` procedure is highlighted by the `register` calling convention and you can freely name functions by calling conventions (you can have e.g. `procedure Stdcall;`), but don't do that ever.

Comment: @TLama If I do that, will it affect the default working of any keyword.

Comment: No, but you would fool yourself. Think about a call like `Stdcall;` somewhere in the code.

Comment: You can name a procedure with any identifier you want, even reserved words. Prefix the name with `&`.

Comment: @RobKennedy thanks Friend to clear me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the unit is included in a designtime-package and this package is installed in the IDE the Register-procedure is called when the package is loaded by the IDE.
It is used to register components, wizards or other IDE-extensions like property-editors to 
the IDE.
Typically you find calls of RegisterComponents() in the implementation of the procedure.
This method is used to register a component to the component-palette of the IDE.

Comment: Thanks buddy It helps a lot to understand concept behind use of `procedure Register;`